# Unable to stub controller components

Tags: scala, playframework

The method `stubControllerComponents` in package `play.api.test` appears to use same package and object name as a separate dependency which is causing a conflict when I attempt to use `stubControllerComponents` :

`play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents` is not found in below code:

```
import java.io.File

import play.api.test
import play.api.mvc._
import javax.inject._
import play.api.Environment
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}


class CountController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents,
                                 env: Environment) extends AbstractController(cc) {

   def getter() = Option(env.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("file.csv"))

}


play.api.Environment(play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents, Environment.simple())
```

This Helpers contains the method I require `stubControllerComponents` :

[image]

But this version of the class is being imported with `import play.api.test` :

[image]

Play link for stubbing : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26#StubControllerComponents

build.sbt:

```
name := "ddd"

version := "1.0" 

lazy val `ddd` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "https://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , ehcache , ws  , guice , specs2 % Test)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

Do I need to exclude portions of a dependency, in this case `filters-helpers` in order to make `stubControllerComponents` available ?

Update:

`play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents` not found:

[image]

Update2:

[image]

Comment: I see no problem. Why do you think there is a conflict? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @cbley please see update.

Comment: Are your sources inside the `Test` scope?

Comment: Probably not. If you're using a scratch file, `Test` artefacts are not available on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a scratch file. AFAICS, there is no way to also include dependencies from your Test scope into the classpath of your worksheet.

A workaround would be to (temporarily) add the play-test artefact to your `libraryDependencies`. Or just create a proper test file, which has access to the Test libraries normally.

Comment: Scala Worksheet can use `test` classpath as long as you create it within `test/` directory instead of `src` or `app`.

Comment: @mario interesting! I only ever created a scratch file using the action, which makes it end up in `/home/claudio/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/scratches/...`

Comment: I have `.sc` inside `.gitignore` and then create worksheets anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents` is provided by `play-test` 
dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % PlayVersion.current % "test",
```

which is indirectly imported by Play's [sbt plugin](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/bfb66a74dc0875cdd89e7892be773e47b711c277/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L81) specified at `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.1")
```

after explicitly `enablePlugins(PlayScala)` within project's `build.sbt`.

Note how `play-test` is out-of-the-box scoped to `test` configuration hence it is provided only on the test classpath. If you wish to reference `stubControllerComponents` from within *IntelliJ Scala Worksheet*, then make sure to create the worksheet inside `test/` directory and not inside `app/` directory. This will make Scala Worksheet use `test` classpath.